# User Provisioning in Spring saml 2.0

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, saml

I have worked on spring saml application. Now i need to user provisioning in my project . Please advice me on that how we achieve USER PROVISIONING SPRING SAML application like Just-in-Time Provisioning in salesforce.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Get user information from SAML response  -In SSO we get a SAML (security assertion mark-up language) request which contains the identifier of the user (the external id or email address) to know which user is trying to login. We need to ask the customer SSO administrator to add the below highlighted attributes/security claims as a minimum to allow us to create users JIT.

```
 <Attribute 
    Name=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/firstname”&gt;
    <AttributeValue>Anuj</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute 
    Name=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/lastname”&gt;
    <AttributeValue>Singh</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute 
    Name=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/useremail”&gt;
    <AttributeValue>anujsingh@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute 
   Name=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name”&gt;
   <AttributeValue>anujsingh@gmail.com</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute 
  Name=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/propertyIdentifie 
 r”&gt;
   <AttributeValue>ABC</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   <Attribute 

  Name=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/userpositionid”&gt;
   <AttributeValue>144</AttributeValue>
   </Attribute>
   </Attribute>
```

Now you can extract all user information from saml response –

```
SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

String userEmail = SpringSAMLUtil.encrypt(credential.getNameID().getValue());

You can get user information from creadential like below –

List attributes = credential.getAttributes();

getAttributes() returns the list of all attributes which contains in SAML response.

After that you can extract user information one by one –

```
for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
if ((attribute.getAttributeValues() != null && 
attribute.getAttributeValues().size() > 0)) {
List<XMLObject> xmlValues = attribute.getAttributeValues();
for (XMLObject attributeValue : xmlValues) {
value = ((XSAnyImpl) attributeValue).getTextContent();
// here you can find all attributes (value) one by one as given sequence 
in SAML response.
}
}
}
```